# returning into clause with dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I have copied and pasted this from http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause.php

But this code goes on and on while executing ...

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t1.id%TYPE;
  l_tab t_tab;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE t1
                     SET    description =' ||'description '||'
                     RETURNING id INTO :l_tab'
 RETURNING  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;
```

FOR i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UPDATE ID=' || l_tab(i));
  END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;

Any mistypes or errors in the code ?

Comment: Any reason for using execute immediate?

Comment: @Lokesh since i want to use dynamic sql , i have to use execute immediate for executing my dql query

Comment: Can you remove execute immediate and try, it will help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `/` at the end of the PL/SQL block to execute it.